# Not able to install Jenkin's Jquery plugin , error message is displayed that saying sha1 does not match

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am facing some issue while installing "Deliver Pipeline Plugin" .The dependency plugin "Jquery Plugin" not installing . I am getting the following error:

```html
I am following your Jenkin's tutorial . I am facing some issue while installing "Deliver Pipeline Plugin" .The dependency plugin "Jquery Plugin" not installing . I am getting the following error:

java.io.IOException: Downloaded file C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\jquery.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-1, expected 'eOnfdKAq1jTJLA6XJ5qfQiXBY6o=', actual 'DIij6KoUcjAFwoa79NMRslzuINs='
 at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.verifyChecksums(UpdateCenter.java:1810)
 at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.access$1100(UpdateCenter.java:149)
 at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob.replace(UpdateCenter.java:1963)
 at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.install(UpdateCenter.java:1194)
 at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1680)
 at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1874)
 at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1651)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
 at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:110)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Please help me to resolve this issue.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: remove the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\jquery.jpi.tmp` and try again

Answer (score -1):

One reason for the above error is the network connectivity.
If you are in any corporate network and you have not set proxy in jenkins then you will get the above error.

Please open C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\jquery.jpi.tmp and see what is written in the file.

To set proxy in jenkins please refer the link in comment section.

Regards,
Anil

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18796907)

Comment: Jenkins Doc to setup proxy: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JenkinsBehindProxy